# MySQL, Incorrect WHERE logic

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table called orders:

```
[database.orders]
uuid | status | data | date
```

I've been relying on an SQL query to return records however it turns out the WHERE clause is wrong.

What i want is records where the uuid is equal to 'xxx' and the status is either equal to 'PROCESSED' or 'PAUSED.

Previous i used: `WHERE status='PROCESSED' OR status='PAUSED' AND uuid = 'xxx'`

 I now see that this returns records where status is processed, or status is paused & uuid = 'xxx'

i've tried the following, but with no success:

`WHERE (uuid = 'xxx' AND status = 'PROCESSED') OR (uuid = 'xxx' AND status = 'PAUSED')`

`WHERE uuid = 'xxx' AND (status = 'PROCESSED' OR status = 'PAUSED')`

As a full query, the statement would appear as `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE uuid = 'xxx' AND (status = 'PROCESSED' OR status = 'PAUSED')`.

**How do i return the expected results as described?**

Comment: `WHERE uuid = 'xxx' AND (status = 'PROCESSED' OR status = 'PAUSED')` condition is correct as per the requirement, however not giving expected result requires some test data to be examined and if possible on http://www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: the last, i think, must work. You can write it as `WHERE uuid = 'xxx' AND status in ('PROCESSED', 'PAUSED')`

Comment: Can you post the full query. The problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: your full query statement is correct, you can also use in clause as suggested by @splash58 just right down query again in your query browser and check results if still facing issue then create a sqlfiddle so that others can check the issue you are not able to find out at this time.

Comment: **Need** sample data, expected result, and your existing full query. Because, as written, your question is answered by `WHERE uuid = 'xxx' AND (status = 'PROCESSED' OR status = 'PAUSED')` so some information is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE (status = 'PROCESSED' OR status = 'PAUSED') AND uuid = 'xxx';
```

This should return you all rows that have the uuid = 'xxx' and the status value in 'Processed' OR 'Status'

So:

```
PKEY | UUID | Status
1      xxx    PROCESSED
2      xxx    PAUSED
3      xxx    PROCESSED
4      xyz    PROCESSED
5      xyz    PAUSED
```

The query will match with the pkey's: 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: it is stated in the question that this where (before being reversed in order) clause did not work

Comment: i managed to get successful query execution using the original query as described. i can only assume it was down to an unseen typo that doesn't appear anymore

Comment: And that's why you are supposed to form a [MCVE] before asking. If the MCVE doesn't reproduce the problem, you have a typo and need not bother anyone; if it does, we can answer it unambiguously.